# How to document processes and concepts for a game?

Tags: architecture, documentation

For the sake of generating a documentation and having a reference for my self, I want to formalize some concepts, behaviors and processes in a proper way.
For example: My game has a game server. This server has to do a reset in some situations. These situations or events could be when all players left the game, the game was lost or one player sends a clear reset intent command.

Now I’m wondering how to formalize that. My first thought was to use a UML-process-diagram. But I have no idea how this should look in a case like the described one (since there are more than just one entry point and also async events).

Maybe I’m wrong and there are better way to formally describe the behavior of some concepts?

Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Do you just want to document technical processes and concepts or also gameplay processes, that are not strictly technical?

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "process" diagram in UML](https://creately.com/blog/diagrams/uml-diagram-types-examples). I am not sure what kind of UML diagram you really mean, but who says that such diagrams must have exactly one entry point? UML is a recommendation, not a mandate. If you have to modify the UML standard a bit to fit your needs, then nobody can stop you.

Comment: @PSquall for now I just want to visualize technical processes like method-calling chains to get an overview for an separation of concerns and getting an Idea of whereI have to put logic into or what classes are in charge when it comes to an implementation of new use cases (like "new exit-event received": Network Manager --> Network-Handler.process(message) --> Match-Controller.sendEndingInformationToClients() )

Comment: @Philipp yeah ur right. I simply looking for a way to visualize or formal describe a typical separation of source-code parts so that a new developer could directly recognize where to put logic parts into. Otherwise it could happen that developer would implement his features in a complete different way an d the src get more and more confusing without any uniformity or possibility of method reuse